# Twilio::REST::RequestError: The 'To' number is not a valid phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

For whatever reason [textris gem](https://github.com/visualitypl/textris) is removing the "+". How can I stop this?

```
class UserTexter < Textris::Base
  default :from => "+15616005697"

  def welcome(user)
    @user = user
    text :to => '+' + @user.number # I've also tried hardcoding "+447576912465"
  end
end
```

**console**

```
UserTexter.welcome(u)
+447576912465 # See it has the plus in it
  Rendered user_texter/welcome.text.erb (0.2ms)
=> #<Textris::Message:0x007fbbffc12ee8
 @action=:welcome,
 @content="Welcome to our system!",
 @from_name="L.T.C.",
 @from_phone="17864206788",
 @texter=UserTexter,
 @to=["447576912465"]> # but then it doesn't show here
[18] pry(main)> UserTexter.welcome(u).deliver
+[+447576912465]
  Rendered user_texter/welcome.text.erb (0.6ms)
Twilio::REST::RequestError: The 'To' number 447576912465 is not a valid phone number. # hence why I get the error here
from /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/twilio-ruby-4.11.1/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/base_client.rb:125:in `connect_and_send'
```

**welcome_text.erb**

```
<p>Test Text</p>
```

How can I fix this? What is the root of the problem? I'm using the [twilio gem](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) to connect to Twilio API.

Comment: Mostly it is `to_i` somewhere..u can check urself in console `"+15616005697".to_i`

Comment: done. It's nothing special @Md.FarhanMemon

Comment: Ya..i realised that later..i updated the comment..check for `to_i` in your code.

Comment: Okay got it. Yea I had tried that @Md.FarhanMemon. Doesn't work :/

Comment: As i can see here https://github.com/visualitypl/textris/blob/master/README.md#example-project the number is without `+`. The error is something else..maybe your configuration.

Comment: I don't know if you have been throigh this but do it https://github.com/visualitypl/textris/blob/master/example/rails-4.2/app/models/user.rb

Comment: In delivery, Textris should add the `+`. See here: https://github.com/visualitypl/textris/blob/master/lib/textris/delivery/twilio.rb#L19-L21. What version of Textris are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Check if your Twilio account is in Trial Mode.

If your account is in Trial Mode, you can only send SMS messages to verified numbers.